# Transferring website: URLs in Full Tiny MCE don't change

Tags: url, tinymce, impresspages

The information provided here are right about menus: 
https://www.impresspages.org/docs/moving-the-website

But they don' seem to work within the links placed within the Full TinyMCE RTE. 
They are written into the DB in absolute instead of relative paths, no matter if an external or internal link. 
Is there a trick besides replacing the domain name withing th database?

Comment: I guess the latestversion that is on GitHub master branch (hasn't been released yet) does url rewrites on all plugins automatically.

Comment: Good to know, thank you!
Does it update automatically after replacing the Ip source folder or do I have to trigger it somehow?

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to save internal link URLs generally with relative instead of absolute path? 
That would make such unnecessary features obsolete :-)

Comment: If you have already done the migration, the update won't fix old URLs. But if you first update files in Ip folder and then do the migration, then you should be fine (not tested in particular with FulltinyMCE widget).

Regarding relative URLs you are almost right. There could be a feature to choose weather you want to use relative or absolute URL's. Absolute URLs are used as they are much easier to update when you change the URL of particular page. Also relative URLs require base tag to be set in head if sub-folder is used. That adds some complication.